# Ant Java Task Output Attribute

Tags: java, ant

Can I check for the Java Task: Output Attribute output="${DESKTOP.LOG.FILE}.${env.LOGFILE_TIMESTAMP}.log

if {DESKTOP.LOG.FILE} = c:\a\b\c\d\desktop
but physically the folder does not exist in the environment running the script, does the Ant Java Task creates the folders for you.
Thank you very much in advance!

```
<target name="start_desktop" description="Start desktop...">
    <property name="loadedClassPath" refid="classpath" />
    <echo file="${CLASSPATH.LOG.FILE}">loadedclasspath=${loadedClassPath}</echo>
    <java classname="${VOPS.DESKTOP.ENTRY}" fork="true" output="${DESKTOP.LOG.FILE}.${env.LOGFILE_TIMESTAMP}.log" error="${DESKTOP.LOG.FILE}.${env.LOGFILE_TIMESTAMP}_err.log">
        <jvmarg value="-Xms64m" />
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx768m" />
        <jvmarg value="-Xss1m" />
        <jvmarg value="-Xoss1m" />
        <jvmarg value="-DUserInfoServices.URL=t3://${env.SERVER.NAME}:7003"/>
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant won't automatically create the folder for you.

You may need to use `mkdir` ant task to create the folder before calling the `java` task.

e.g.

```
<dirname property="dirToCreate" file="${DESKTOP.LOG.FILE}" />
<mkdir dir="${dirToCreate}" />
```